Overlapping Video Frames in RPBroadcastSampleHandler with ReplayKit
On iOS, when using ReplayKit to record the screen, overlapping video frames appear in the callback of RPBroadcastSampleHandler.
I am recording video on iOS using ReplayKit and found that after copying data in the processSampleBuffer:withType: callback using memcpy, the data changes. This occurs particularly frequently when the screen content changes rapidly, making it look like the frames are overlapping.
image
I found that the values starting from byte 672 in the video data on my device often change. Here is the test demo:
- (void)processSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer withType:(RPSampleBufferType)sampleBufferType {
    switch (sampleBufferType) {
        case RPSampleBufferTypeVideo: {
            CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
            
            int ret = 0;
            uint8_t *oYData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
            size_t oYSize = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0) * CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
            
            uint8_t *oUVData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
            size_t oUVSize = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1) * CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
            if (oYSize <= 672) {
                return;
            }
            uint8_t tempValue = oYData[672];
            
            uint8_t *tYData = malloc(oYSize);
            memcpy(tYData, oYData, oYSize);
            if (tYData[672] != oYData[672]) {
                NSLog(@"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:%d o:%d temp:%d", tYData[672], oYData[672], tempValue);
            }
            free(tYData);
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }
}

Output:
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:110 o:124 temp:110
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:111 o:133 temp:111
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:124 o:138 temp:124
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:133 o:144 temp:133
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:138 o:151 temp:138
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:144 o:156 temp:144
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:151 o:135 temp:151
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:156 o:78 temp:156
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:135 o:76 temp:135
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:78 o:77 temp:78
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:76 o:80 temp:76
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:77 o:80 temp:77
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:80 o:79 temp:80
$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$------ t:79 o:80 temp:79


I don't have iOS but is there a way to set a recording frame rate?

There are no functions or configurations for setting the frame rate.

(1) So processSampleBuffer can't happen on a Timer (eg: 30 times per second)? (2) What happens if you don't involve BufferLock (eg: is now getting a better picture)? (3) What happens if you make *oYData and *oUVData into global variables so it's not making a new uint8_t every time? Or is it required to be that way? (4) Your return should ideally first print a message to notify that a size was incorrect  and clear the *oYData & *oUVData buffers instead of just silently returning to the rest of program code.

Thanks @VC.One (1) processSampleBuffer:withType: is a method of RPBroadcastSampleHandler, called by ReplayKit after capturing audio or video.
(2) To access CVPixelBuffer data on the CPU, you must lock it first.
(3) ReplayKit passes in a new frame each time processSampleBuffer is called, so a new data object must be created each time.
(4) This is just test code to verify that CVPixelBuffer changes before and after copying. I initially wanted to rotate the frame, but incorrect images appeared. Testing showed that errors occurred even with just copying.
